# How to load youtube video in jquery?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I want to load a youtube file in a js function.

This is the code i have tried:

when i used the link within quotes, it load youtube file.

for example,

```
function loadVideo(){            
 var image=$('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" />');
 image.attr('src',"http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k");              
 $('#screen2').html(image); 
}
```

But when i retrieve the link via getAttribute() it doesn't load that youtube file.

The code is,

```
function loadVideo(){       
 var videopath='<%=request.getAttribute("videofile")%>';     
 var image=$('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" />');
 image.attr('src',videopath);               
 $('#screen2').html(image); 
}
```

Please reply. thanks in advance...

Comment: have you checked value of `videopath`?

Comment: proper escaping (?SP => JS => HTML)

Comment: yes. i checked videopath value is same youtube file.

Comment: proper escaping means? sorry, i can't understand.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Are those ASP tags, just like PHP? And haven't you written this code in .js file? ;)

Comment: it is in jsp and i am using inline script

Answer (score 0):

Is the JavaScript written inline in the document? Or is it in a separate .js-file? If it is in the separate .js-file, you will not be able to get the ASP tag evaluated. You will have to make the `loadVideo` call inline from the document.

.js-file:

```
function loadVideo(src){            
 var image=$('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" />');
 image.attr('src',src);
 $('#screen2').html(image); 
}
```

inline in the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    loadVideo('<%=request.getAttribute("videofile")%>');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i m using inline script and calling from html div onclick() as <div onclick="loadVideo(<%=request.getAttribute("videofile")%>);"></div>

Comment: Can you tell if you get any error messages? In any case, you most likely have to put a " or ' around the video url, like this: `loadVideo('<%=request.getAttribute("videofile")%>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div onclick="loadVideo('<%=request.getAttribute("videofile")%>');"></div>
```